# Viewing controller data in VIEW

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

i'm newbie to MVC 3.0 and LINQ to SQL. called store procedure and saved it result in VAR but now how to view it's data in VIEW ?

CODE:

```
using EmployeeAttendance_app.Models;
namespace EmployeeAttendance_app.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Employee Attendance";
            var DataContext = new EmployeeAtdDataContext();
            var EmployeeAtd = DataContext.GetAttendance_Sp;
            return View(EmployeeAtd);
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

SP:

```
Select * from V_EmpAtd
```

View:

```
@foreach (GetAttendance_SpResult emp in (IEnumerable<Object>)ViewData.Model) 
 {
     <li>@emp.DeptName</li>
 }
```

this view shows the results, successfully :) but i don't understand that why do i need "GetAttendance_SpResult" in foreach and how

```
return View(EmployeeAtd);
```

in controller is related to this ?

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I suggest to read a tutorial about MVC: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3

Comment: i read, sevearl times but doing something on own needs research a bit sir

Comment: If you want a good answer, write a complete question ;-)
Add the code of your View and your Model for example, and show us you have followed the tutorials

Answer (score 0):

right click within your action and select 'Create View'

public ActionResult Index()
        {  // right click here...

then visit the view /HomeController

Comment: So you have a view and don't know how to enter the url?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your model? "M" "V" "C" ;-)

First you should create a class (your model, called for example EmployeeModel- you should take a name corresponding to the type of your data) corresponding to the fields of your items of your database results. How? Look here:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-a-model

The list of items corresponding to that model will be passed to your View in your controller so your view should start with:

```
@model IEnumerable<yourNameSpace.Models.EmployeeModel>
```

And then in your view you will be able to display the properties of your item. Sample for a table:

```
<table>    
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DeptName)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

But you can do what you want: a list, ...

In a few words: back to MVC basics. See sample here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller, especially when they are in "Examining the Generated Code".